# How do I prove the number of derangements formula $nD_{n - 1} + (-1)^n$ intuitively?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, derangements

I found that the series of number of derangements follows a certain sequence that can be expressed as such : $nD_{n-1} +(-1)^n$.

Now, I found others saying it can be expressed as follows $(n-1)(D_{n-1}+D_{n-2})$.

I have seen some people explaining the second formula intuitively. What I am curious about is , whether there is a way to explain the FIRST formula intuitively. I want an explanation for the first  formula. Meaning, I am trying to find the logic for it in such a way that the expression as it's written would be understood.

I started somewhat by saying that there is some logic behind the number of derangements of $D_{n-1}$ to be multiplied by $n$ because the new object has $n$ places to be placed in while $n-1$ objects are placed as was ordered in $D_{n-1}$. But I can't seem to find the logic behind the $-1^n$. I started to think that maybe for odd numbers I have to reduce one due to the middle? But I am not sure.

I want a logical/intuitive proof that would prove MY (first) formula and I want it to be followed somehow in the way I started. I don't want completely different proofs.

But can someone please make some sense of my proof or show why it's wrong? Or show other intuitive thing to my formula?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prove the number of dearangaments intuitivly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760897/how-do-i-prove-the-number-of-dearangaments-intuitivly)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Since this version has been edited, I opted to close the other version.

Comment: I posted the other question but mistakenly in the CS section instead of math.  So I posted it here. And voted to flag the one in CS.   THX

Comment: See [Arthur T. Benjamin and Joel Ornstein, *A bijective proof of a derangement recurrence*, Fibonacci Quarterly, vol. 55, issue 5](https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/55-5/BenjaminOrnstein.pdf) for a bijective proof (which I would not call intuitive -- but I think it's the closest we can get).

Comment: There's also this paper by Jeffrey Remmel: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669883800341